# In spacy, how can I make sure a particular character is always considered a full token?

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize, spacy

In spacy, I'd like characters like '€', '$', or '¥' to be always considered a token. However it seems sometimes they are made part of a bigger token.
For example, this is good (two tokens)

```
>>> len(nlp("100€"))
2
```

But the following is not what I want (I'd like to obtain two tokens in this case also):

```
>>> len(nlp("N€"))
1
```

How could I achieve that with spacy?
By the way, don't get too focused on the currency example. I've had this kind of problematic with other kind of characters that have nothing to do with numbers or currencies. The problem is how to make sure a character is always treated as a full token and not glued to some other string in the sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see [here](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#native-tokenizer-additions).

Spacy’s tokenizer works by iterating over whitespace-separated substrings and looking for things like for prefixes or suffixes, to separate those parts off.
You can add custom prefixes and suffixes as explained in the link above.

We can use that as follows:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

doc = nlp("N€")
print([t for t in doc])
#[N€]

suffixes = nlp.Defaults.suffixes + ("€", )

suffix_regex = spacy.util.compile_suffix_regex(suffixes)
nlp.tokenizer.suffix_search = suffix_regex.search


doc = nlp("N€")
print([t for t in doc])
#[N, €]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That seems to be exactly what I need. However in your link they say to add '$' at the end of an added suffix (and '^') for a prefix? Do I have to do that? Are the prefixes/suffixes regular expressions? Actually that would be useful if they were as I could define a whole range of suffixes in one go.

Comment: Your solution works so I accepted it. I still don't know why the documentation seems to advise to do something that actually doesn't work. Anyway, thanks a lot for the help.